# Mock Postman Server with API's having the same End Points

Tags: collections, mocking, postman

I created a mock server for a postman collection which has 2 POST API calls with the same end point (path) i.e. {{url}}/group. The API takes in a unique request body.

I created an example for each POST based on the request body and response but the tests fails on POST 2 as it uses POST 1 response details, presumably since the path is the same? Is there a way round this?

POST 1 - Request Body

> {
>     "id": 1, "groupName": "CompanyName 1"
>     "begin": "2018-07-07T12:00Z",
>     "end": "2018-07-07T12:00Z"
>     ]
>   }

POST 2 - Request Body

> {
>     "id": 2, "groupName": "CompanyName 2"
>     "begin": "2018-08-07T12:00Z",
>     "end": "2018-08-07T12:00Z"
>     ]
>   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out one solution to add **x-mock-response-name** as a KEY in the request header and give it the specific value of the example defined for the request

Comment: You deserve this!